# Conditional probability based on tabulated data

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I have a table of containing data that shows the "likes" and "dislikes of football and basketball for a population where:

```
                              Doesn't like basketball     Likes basketball
Doesn't like football                  0.7                   0.1
Likes football                         0.05                  0.15
```

I'm trying to **find the probability** of a person **liking football** **given that the person does not like basketball.**

Here's where i get confused. Conditional probability is given by:

```
P(X = x | Y = y) = P(x  ∩  y) / P(y)
```

So I'm torn between two choices, my first attempt was to obtain the probability straight from the table above where

```
P(likes football | does not like basketball) = 0.05 #since they intersect
```

and when i follow the equation above,

```
P(likes football | does not like basketball) = 0.05/(0.7 + 0.05)
                                             = 0.0666 or 1/15
```

I was wondering which of the attempts are the correct solution to the problem. Would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Your first value of $1/20$ is the *joint* probability $P(X = x, Y = y)$, and the second value of $1/15$ is the *conditional* probability $P(X = x \mid Y = y)$.

Comment: @BrianTung so I'm guessing that the second attempt was the correct one? Since conditional probability has the keyword "given that"?

Comment: Yes, it means something along the lines of "Suppose you look only at the set of people who don't like basketball.  Out of just those people, what proportion like football?"  The answer to that question is $(1/20)/(3/4) = 1/15$.

Answer (score 1):

It's often helpful to look at simpler examples:

```
                              Doesn't like basketball     Likes basketball
Doesn't like football                  0                     0.8
Likes football                         0.05                  0.15
```

In this example, what's the probability of the person liking football, given that the person doesn't like basketball? The first approach says $0.05$, the second approach says $1$. Which one is right?

Answer (score 0):

Some people find thinking about integers easier

Suppose there were $100$ people in your population.  Then the numbers involved would be

```
                              Doesn't like basketball     Likes basketball
Doesn't like football                  70                   10
Likes football                          5                   15
```

- How many do not like basketball?
- Of those who do not like basketball, how many do like football?
- What proportion of those who do not like basketball, do like football?